# What is this process running?

Tags: cmd.exe, process

I've a process that runs and a CMD pops up for a fraction of a second.
Procmon shows this
[image]

The process inspection shows this

[image]

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `AppData\Roaming\aveebtf`?

Comment: No, how do I do that? In the AppData folder, it just says "File".

Comment: Scan it with your antivirus or upload it to an online check like virustotal.com

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ac1a3f21fcc88f9cee7bf51581eafba24cc76c924f0821deb2afdf1080ddf3d3/community It looks that it's installutil.exe?? How weird...